# Filter or Search JSON Data

Tags: java, android, json, search, filter

I have created a filterable method in my adapter class. The plan is for this method to allow the user to filter through the JSON data for a specific article. Everything looks right to me but when I run the application it crashes. I am still a bit new to programming so I don't know if this code is the issue or not. Any assistance rendered would be greatly appreciated.

The errorLog reads this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView
    at newsapp.news.onCreateOptionsMenu(news.java:177)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3496)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:378)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2549)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1589)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1869)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:230)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:205)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6892)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
```

---

Here is my filter code:

```
 public Filter getFilter(){
    return newsFilter;
}

private Filter newsFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        List<newsItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() ==0){
            filteredList.addAll(mNewsListFull);
        }else {
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (newsItem item : mNewsListFull){
                if (item.getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {

                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values= filteredList;

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        mNewsList.clear();
        mNewsList.addAll((List)results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Here is my news activity code where I call the menu inflater

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)searchItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            mNewsAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

And ofcourse here is my menu xml code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".news"
>

<item

   android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
```

Comment: share error i.e error which causes crash

Comment: @ShivamOberoi error code added to the top

Comment: Any assistance guys

Comment: @Shane show your error log because above code doesn't show your error.

Comment: @Niceumang when I open the log and and I switch from 'verbose' to 'error' that's the only error i see

Comment: @Shane when error generate set "No Filters" in last dropdown box of logcat instead of "show only selected applications".

Comment: @Niceumang Oh wow. Was wondering why errots werent showing. Ok I added error code

Comment: In your FragmentActivity.class file at most where you import your all packages in that replace "android.widget.SearchView" with "androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" .

Comment: @Niceumang this did the trick. Thanks again man

Comment: @Shane Welcome bruh